# PHP Warning: Access Denied when GAE app try to access a bucket

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I use the simple exemple in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/
but i received the Warning Access Denied like answer, here the PHP code :

function accessGS(){

```
$options = [ "gs" => [ "Content-Type" => "text/plain" ]];
$ctx = stream_context_create($options);
file_put_contents("gs://mbucket/mFile.txt", "Hello", 0, $ctx);
return file_get_contents("gs://mBucket/mFile.txt");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to allow read access the bucket from your app.

In the [cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/console):

1. choose your project
2. click "Cloud Storage" from left navigation
3. select the bucket in question (click on checkbox not rest or line)
4. add user (with desired permissions) (get user email from permission in left navigation)

[image: Cloud Console - Cloud SQL bucket permissions]